# Best practises for a Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Movies table with some basic information and a Reviews table with revies about the movies.

In my app I want to show a list with the name and the avg score of the movie. What is the best practise?

Do I store an avg field in the Movies table and use the API/Movies?

Do I have my API return Movies including the reviews reviews and calculating that in my app (I guess not).

Or Do all the necessary calcs on the server and return the View Model needed?

Comment: Asking for best practice is not a good format for question on Stack Overflow. Having said that, you should calculate in the database/API and send the data to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the calcs done on the server/database. Assuming you have a back-end db store like SQL server, write a query, stored procedure, or view that does the calc for you on demand. You don't need to calculate this on the client (this would be slow and cause you to need to transfer too much data) and you don't need to store that average anywhere.

Comment: Just wanted to add that storing the average could make sense, but only in a genuine 'big data' scenario where read performance is significantly more important than write performance.

Comment: I agree with @elolos, there comes a point that it might make sense to store the average - but given the nature of question thought that was unlikely to be necessary in this case.